# How to get time of page's first paint

Tags: javascript, web-performance

While it is easy enough to get `firstPaint` times from dev tools, is there a way to get the timing from JS?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is part of the [paint timing API](https://github.com/WICG/paint-timing).

You probably want the timing for `first-contentful-paint`, which you can get using:

```
const paintTimings = performance.getEntriesByType('paint');
const fmp = paintTimings.find(({ name }) => name === "first-contentful-paint");
enter code here
console.log(`First contentful paint at ${fmp.startTime}ms`);
```

Comment: Note that this will only work in Chrome for now: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformancePaintTiming

Answer (score 2):

Recently new browser APIs like [PerformanceObserver](https://w3c.github.io/performance-timeline/#the-performanceobserver-interface) and [PerformancePaintTiming](https://w3c.github.io/paint-timing/#performancepainttiming) have made it easier to retrieve First Contentful Paint (FCP) by Javascript.

I made a JavaScript library called [Perfume.js](http://zizzamia.github.io/perfume/) which works with few lines of code

```
const perfume = new Perfume({
  firstContentfulPaint: true
});
// ⚡️ Perfume.js: First Contentful Paint 2029.00 ms
```

I realize you asked about First Paint (FP) but would suggest using First Contentful Paint (FCP) instead.

> The primary difference between the two metrics is FP marks the point
>   when the browser renders anything that is visually different from what
>   was on the screen prior to navigation. By contrast, FCP is the point
>   when the browser renders the first bit of content from the DOM, which
>   may be text, an image, SVG, or even a canvas element.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof(PerformanceObserver)!=='undefined'){ //if browser is supporting
const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
for (const entry of list.getEntries()) {
     console.log(entry.entryType);
     console.log(entry.startTime);
     console.log(entry.duration);
   }
  });
  observer.observe({entryTypes: ['paint']});
}
```

this will help you just paste this code in starting of your js app before everything else.